# Self with Python 2.7 and GUI using pyside and qt designer

Tags: python, user-interface, qt-designer

So I have the following code in my 'MainLogin.py file, which is the main file. I'm using 'mainLoginTest' file as my GUI py file. Whenever I start the program with this code it prints 'hello':

```
class MainDialog(QMainWindow, mainLoginTest.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.connect(self.submitBtn, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.submittedPress())



    def submittedPress(self):
        print('hello')
```

But when I make the self.connect line without the () after 'submittedPress' like I'll show below, it does nothing.

```
self.connect(self.submitBtn, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.submittedPress)
```

How is the 'self' working here? Because it's obviously reaching my 'MainLogin' file, but I don't know where it has gone when I take away the '()'. 
I have the 'mainLoginTest' on another .py file in the same directory. The program is working, but not correctly. I just wanted to give a little history. This is the code within my 'mainLoginTest' file:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(830, 523)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/angryFace.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        self.submitBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.loginPage)
```

Thanks guys. Hopefully this isn't a dumb question. I'm fairly new. If someone could provide a good resource for understanding everything that would be great too. I want to learn about everything I can.

Comment: if you use () you are invoking the function and therefore it will print the text, but if you want it to be called when the button is pressed you should only pass it the name of the function without ()

Comment: what is `loginPage`?

Comment: Here logingPage is the default starting page. I can post all the code if you would like. I just didn't want to oversaturate it with too much unneeded code. I'm trying to reverse engineer how these things work so I can understand them. So this would help me see how everything is connected.

Comment: Reverse engineering for what is known its operation? Nobody asks you to publish a lot of unnecessary code, if you have read [ask] you should understand that you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: I recommend reading about python, the official website offers much of that type of resources, the same for PyQt, there are a lot of tutorials on the internet. SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: I was asking why it wasn't doing what I think it should be doing. That's all. Sorry. I was asking because I want to know why it's not going back to the self within my 'MainLogin' page. I just said that I would like to know why it wasn't so that I can learn from it. I'm not asking for tutoring. I just want to know the reason. I mean, I'm sure the answer would help me understand too if that is what you're saying is the only thing I should be seeking.

Comment: improve your question, do not ask for off-line resources, that's off-topic in SO. Focus on your original problem, provide a correct [mcve], and we will be happy to help you.

Comment: Ok thanks eyllanesc

Comment: **read** [ask]!!!!

Comment: @NickolasKent. Don't use that old-style syntax for connecting signals. It's too easy to get it wrong and it doesn't raise an exception if you try to connect to a signal that doesn't exist. That is why your code doesn't work: QPushButton does not have a "triggered" signal. So always use the new-style syntax, like this: `self.submitBtn.clicked.connect(self.submittedPress)`.

Comment: Awesome, yea, that old style apparently is garbage. The new style is much easier